# How to show the resulting function hidden by Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I have

```
u0[r_, phi_] := Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -n, n}];
Limit[u0[r, phi], n -> Infinity]
```

but the result is not exportable to TEX, as it is hidden. How do I unhide it?

Thanks

Comment: Is the problem that the `DifferenceRoot`s are Iconized ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: You could try something like `TeXForm[result /. DifferenceRoot -> Dr]` and the `DifferenceRoot`s will show up as $\text{Dr}(...)$.

Comment: Will give it a try. The Difference roots look far better when you click on the icon, and they appear as functions, rather than Dr. Can't these be brought forward as text?

Comment: The things you see in there are not the results of the roots but the inputs - they are the equations that define them and they should show up inside the $\text{Dr}(...)$. Normally applying `DifferenceRootReduce` would simplify these but it appears to be too difficult.

Comment: :( But at least, one can say that this series is not divergent..

Comment: Try `TeXForm[lim /. DifferenceRoot -> HoldForm[DifferenceRoot]]`.  If this is for a paper, I think you're better off introducing a notation for representing the `DifferenceRoot`s, and then writing the result in terms of that notation.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code

```
fun = Sum[I^(-n) BesselJ[n, r] Exp[I n phi], {n, -k, k}];
pl = Position[fun, DifferenceRoot[_]];
fun1 = Table[{Subscript[f, i] @@ fun[[pl[[i, 1]], 0, 1, 1]] == 
   fun[[pl[[i, 1]], 0, 1, 2]]}, {i, Length@pl}] /.
    {\[FormalY] -> y, \[FormalN] -> n};
ReplacePart[fun, Table[pl[[i]] -> Subscript[f, i], {i, Length@pl}]]
    // TeXForm
```

yielding
$$ f_1(k+1)+f_2(k+1)-J_0(r) $$
and then

```
fun1 // TeXForm
```

yielding
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 f_1(y,n)=\left\{e^{2 i \phi } r y(n)-e^{i \phi } y(n+1) \left(2 i n+e^{i \phi } r+2 i\right)+y(n+2)
   \left(2 i n e^{i \phi }+2 i e^{i \phi }-r\right)+r y(n+3)=0,y(0)=0,y(1)=J_0(r),y(2)=J_0(r)-i e^{i
   \phi } J_1(r)\right\} \\
 f_2(y,n)=\left\{e^{2 i \phi } r y(n)+y(n+1) \left(-2 i n e^{3 i \phi }-e^{2 i \phi } r-2 i e^{3 i
   \phi }\right)-e^{3 i \phi } y(n+2) \left(-2 i n+e^{i \phi } r-2 i\right)+e^{4 i \phi } r
   y(n+3)=0,y(0)=0,y(1)=J_0(r),y(2)=J_0(r)-i e^{-i \phi } J_1(r)\right\} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where some manual editing may be needed.